# How should I set enviroment variables at GNOME login - not shell?

Tags: gnome, bash, scripts, environment-variables

Ubuntu 12.04, GNOME Classic

I have a script that I execute from `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Whenever I open a terminal, it sets some environment variables needed for my applications to run. I execute them from the terminal, and viola, everything runs fine.

Recently I made some desktop launchers for my applications so I don't have to open the terminal to execute them, but found that my applications don't work properly this way because the `environment_setup.sh` has not been executed.

How should I set these variables, so that I can use my applications without the need for a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the environment variables in your `~/.profile`. This file is sourced by display managers such as [LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) which start the X server and the rest of the graphical system.

It’s also sourced by Bash (as long as `~/.bash_profile` doesn’t exist) – and other POSIX shells – for non-graphical, i.e., network and console logins.

The Ubuntu Wiki has lots of good information on [environment
variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables).

Comment: +1 for posting that helpful link for me on environment variables, but I ended up creating a symbolic link to `neuro_env_setup.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` because the set up script is actually via NFS. That did it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using bash.bashrc because I wanted the setup process to be system wide, so putting it in `~/.profile`, as Anthony suggested, was not the best solution for me. Additionally the setup script was located on an NFS, so I made symbolic link in `/etc/profile.d` that pointed to the location of the setup script on the NFS. Works great now!